# How to convert/update the key-values information in defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, list-comprehension, defaultdict

How do I convert the following `defaultdict()`?

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {
  'key1_A': {
    'id': 'key1',
    'length': '663', 
    'type': 'A'},
  'key1_B': {
    'id': 'key1',
    'length': '389',
    'type': 'B'},
  'key2_A': {
    'id': 'key2',
    'length': '865',
    'type': 'A'},
  'key2_B': {
    'id': 'key2',
    'length': '553',
    'type': 'B' ........}})
```

- the `value of the id i.e key1` becomes the key, and the `key called length` is changed to `length_A or B` with corresponding values belonging in the earlier `type`.

  `defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {
    'key1': {
      'length_A': '663', 
      'length_B': '389'},
    'key2': {
      'length_A': '865',
      'length_B': '553'}})`

Thanks,

Comment: Where's your code so far? Do you have a specific issue you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

d = {
    'key1_A': {
        'id': 'key1',
        'length': '663', 
        'type': 'A',
    },
    'key1_B': {
        'id': 'key1',
        'length': '389',
        'type': 'B',
    },
    'key2_A': {
        'id': 'key2',
        'length': '865',
        'type': 'A',
    },
    'key2_B': {
        'id': 'key2',
        'length': '553',
        'type': 'B',
    },
}

transformed = defaultdict(dict)
for v in d.values():
    transformed[v["id"]]["length_{}".format(v["type"])] = v["length"]

pprint.pprint(transformed)

# Output:
# defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
#             {'key1': {'length_A': '663', 'length_B': '389'},
#              'key2': {'length_A': '865', 'length_B': '553'}})
```